# Android App execute code on unknown button click

Tags: android, keydown

I am working on an android app to run as a front end on my Parrot Asteroid Smart which runs a modified version of gingerbread as my cars headunit.

At present the unit natively senses the reverse gear signal and displays a "complete action using" dialog which displays one of two camera applications.

I don't have a camera but what I want to do when it senses reverse is to reduce the volume to a set value.  I have completed the code to do volume adjustment, however.

I am having an issue determining what button input or trigger the reverse gear is producing.  I have already tried some code which logs the onKeyDown event which I have confirmed works when I click the menu or back button but when I trigger the reverse signal there is no log for a keydown.

Although I have a number of years experience in other languages I am new to android app development and java so no suggestion is to ridiculous at this time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code. What happened? What did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the reverse gear is triggering an `Intent` since it displays the app chooser dialog. It is probably sending a `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent or something similar that will require a camera app to complete. If that is the case, then you could modify your app and register to receive those intents and handle them however you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the response ebarrenechea, I will look into your suggestion, that was the direction I was thinking I might have to go in but the intent name is helpful as I wouldn't have known where to start.

I guess my logic is a physical input into the hardware must be triggering something to call the intent.  If I could work out what from logs or debug code that would be a better solution.  In the meantime I will look into the MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent.